# dynamic variable declaration

Tags: matlab, variables, declaration

Suppose we have loaded data into cell array:

```
DATA={'foo',[1,5];'bar',[2,6]}
```

Is there way how to declare variables named by 1st column in `DATA` with content of 2nd column?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using `eval`

```
for ii = 1:size(DATA,1)
    eval( [DATA{ii,1}, ' = ', num2str( DATA{ii,2} )] );
end
```

However, use of `eval` is [**not recommended**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

You **can** use dynamic field names instead:

```
s = cell2struct( DATA(:,2), DATA(:,1), 2 );
```

Comment: this won't cover cases where the variable is not a vector, such as a ND matrix (or even a 2D matrix), cell array, structs, etc

Comment: @carandraug you are right. I used `num2str` instead of my personal favorite `sprintf` just to cover simple vectors. But `eval` has indeed limitations here. Maybe combined with `disp`? I prefer struct with dynamic names...

Answer (score 1):

There's an `assignin` function which takes a variable name and assign to it a specific value:

```
for r = 1:size (DATA, 1)
  assignin ('caller', DATA{r,:});
end
```

Comment: this will not work in a function. or worse, it will work with unexpected results: variables will be assigned in `'base'` instead of in the context of the function :O

Comment: @Shai ups! You're correct. I misunderstood `base` and `caller`, I thought `caller` was 1 level down in the stack, and base the current scope.