# how to store data without dynamically naming variables

Tags: matlab

I have 40 variables. The 40 variables names are in a cell array (40 x 1).

Each variable will have a matrix. The matrix is of type of double and will be size 5000 x 150. It will also have a vector of size 1 x 150 & one last vector 1 x 4.

Initially I was going to dynamically name each struct with its variable name in the cell array. So would look like something like below (assuming variable name is ABC),

```
ABC.dataMatrix
ABC.dataVec
ABC.summaryData
```

All the variables would be saved to a directory.

However I've read using eval isn't a very good idea so guessing my idea isn't the best way to go about this problem. What would be the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: Why not using array of struct? Like `ABC(i).dataMatrix`. It is not clear why you would have to use `eval`.

Comment: why not use [dynamic field names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21832018/1714410)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `struct` arrays with [dynamic field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831692), as @Shai and @RobertStettler suggest.

However, another option is a `table`. This might be more appealing if you want to see your data in one big matrix, and you can give each `table` row the name of your variables too! Note that the rows in a `table` would then be what you call your variables, but MATLAB calls the `table` columns its variables.

Also note that using a `table` can be more difficult than using `struct` or `cell` arrays, but if you know how to use them, you can handle a `table` too.

An example:

```
% create dummy data
rowNames = {'a';'b';'c'};
M = {ones(3); zeros(3); nan(3)}; % a cell, one element per item in rowNames
V = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]; % a matrix of vectors, each row containing a vector for every item in rowNames

% create a table
T = table(M,V,'RowNames',rowNames); % this is where your variable names could go
```

Now, to access data you could use (some examples):

- `T(2,:)` or `T('b',:)`, return a `table` for all data on the `'b'` row.
- `T(:,2)` or `T(:,'V')`, return a `table` of variable `V` for all rows.
- `T.V` or `T{:,2}` or `T{:,'V'}` or `T.(2)`, return matrix `V` for all rows. This syntax is similar to accessing a (dynamic) field name of a `struct`.
- `T{3,1}` or `T{'c',1}` or `T.M('c')`, return `cell` `M` for row `'c'`. This syntax is similar to accessing a `cell`, but with more advanced possibilities, i.e. the ability to access the table via row or variable names.
- `T{3,1}{:}` or `T{'c',1}{:}` or `T.M{'c'}`, return `cell` contents `M` for row `'c'`.

And even more complex: `T('a',:).M{:}` is a complex way of accessing the cell content of `M` for row `'a'`, which can be done with `T{1,1}{:}` or `T.M{'a'}` or `T{'a','M'}{:}` or `T.M{1}` as well.

In your case you would en up with a `40x3 table`, with every row what you call a variable and the first column the matrices (in `cell` arrays), and the last two columns the vectors (as well in `cell` arrays or as a `40xm double`, `m` being the length of your vector).